# "Рубаха-парень"

Tags: фразеология

О простом открытом человеке говорят "рубаха-парень". А почему - рубаха? От того, что он отдаст последнюю рубашку или тут другой смысл?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ЭТИМОЛОГИЯ

Слово «рубашка» произошло от «рубаха», «рубъ», «рубище» - грубая ткань, подрубленная (подшитая) одежда. Отсюда и возникло выражение «рубаха-парень» о простом, прямом, грубоватом, но добром человеке. Рубаха была самым простым видом одежды, для шитья которой ткань не резали, а отрывали.

УПОТРЕБЛЕНИЕ В РЕЧИ

Просторечные выражения рубаха-парень, человек-рубаха известны не позднее начала XVIII в.  Однако это выражение до середины XIX в. носило областной характер. Оно вошло в «Опыт областного великорусского словаря» в 1852 году со значением "простой человек, простяк".

У И. С. Тургенева в «Дыме»: «Григорий Литвинов, рубашка-парень, русская душа, рекомендую, — воскликнул Бамбаев, подводя Литвинова к человеку небольшого роста и помещичьего склада...».

У П. Д. Боборыкина в романе «Китай-город»: «Я думал, из вас Чичиков выйдет, а вы — человек-рубашка». У него же в романе «На ущербе»: «Ты его и по батюшке знаешь? — Как не знать, сударь. Барин — рубашка!.. И овсеца когда купишь у них... в кредитец».

У А. П. Чехова в повести «Дуэль»: «Самойленко... видел в Лаевском доброго малого, студента, человека-рубаху, с которым можно было и выпить, и посмеяться, и потолковать по душе» (гл. 1).

У М. Горького в рассказе «Супруги Орловы»: «Этакой-то рубаха-парень, а? Рабочему, говорит, человеку в меру выпить всегда следует... слышь, Мотря? Ну-ка, нацеди мне рюмочку, — есть, что ли?».

http://wordhist.narod.ru/rubaha-paren.html